# Where's my Network Alias list in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I can't select any Network Alias from the Network Alias Drop-down.

My TNSNames.ora file is in C:\Oracle

My other machine that is a fresh install doesn't have this problem.

I get an error when I click `Test` on the connection window.

```
Status :Failure - Test failed: no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path
```

I'm guessing somehow it's not pointing to the `TNSNames.ora` file.

Where is that configured? 
[image]

Comment: Is your %TNS_ADMIN% env variable set? Which Oracle client have you got installed (instant client/full oracle client)? Is %ORACLE_HOME% set?

Comment: Yes TNS_ADMIN = "C:\Oracle"
    ORACLE_HOME = "C:\Oracle\instalclient_10_2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tnsnames.ora should be located in TNS_ADMIN, which is defined as `ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/`.

Go to a command prompt (assuming Windows from your mention of "c:\") and execute the following:

```
echo %TNS_ADMIN%

echo %ORACLE_HOME%
```

Verify the directories returned, make sure that your tnsnames.ora file is in there.

Comment: And for anyone who comes after me see: http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14048_02/pbr_rfap.htm